# Crosstab query to only show the previous 4 weeks

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am open to suggestions on changing the way I have started to lay out my data.

**What I need:**
I need to display a list of individuals performance week on week. To do this I have created a crosstab query with each column showing as the date (built using the query wizard).

The query actually functions fine, although I only want to show 4 columns (being 4 weeks worth of data) but really don't know where to start giving me doubt that I have taken the correct approaching using a cross tab.

because there is no conditioning its showing the full year being almost over 50 columns

**Current Code:**

```
TRANSFORM Max(tbl_Genesys_Weekly.[Field32]) AS MaxOfField32
SELECT [_tbl_Structure].[User Name]
FROM _tbl_Structure INNER JOIN tbl_Genesys_Weekly ON [_tbl_Structure].[User ID] = tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field5
GROUP BY [_tbl_Structure].[User Name]
ORDER BY tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date
PIVOT tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date;
```

Any help is hugely appreciated

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
TRANSFORM Max(Format([Field32]/100,"Percent")) AS Calc
SELECT [_tbl_Structure].CSM, [_tbl_Structure].[User Name]
FROM _tbl_Structure INNER JOIN tbl_Genesys_Weekly ON [_tbl_Structure].[User ID] = tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field5
GROUP BY [_tbl_Structure].CSM, [_tbl_Structure].[User Name]
ORDER BY tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date DESC 
PIVOT DatePart("ww", tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date)
WHERE DateDiff("ww", tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date, Date()) Between 5 and 1;
```

**ERROR RECEIVED:**
Characters found after end of SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
PIVOT DatePart("ww", tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date);
```

and include a where clause:

```
WHERE DateDiff("ww", tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date, Date()) Between 5 and 1
```

Note, that if you use standard ISO 8601 weeknumbers, DatePart cannot be used, and the year will have to included to obtain the correct sorting around New Year.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I can see what this will essentially do. Putting it in to practice is causing problems. I have updated my question with the code how I think it should look but does not work. Thanks in advance

Comment: PIVOT must be the last statement. WHERE goes between FROM and GROUP BY,

Comment: Thank you - New error received: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'tbl_Genesys_Weekly.WC_Date' as part of an aggregate function

Comment: Remove the ORDER BY and/or adjust/build the Select query in the GUI designer, then change it to a crosstab.